# accessing jquery class names for recursively added fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I have a form that allows a user to add an unlimited number of extra rows (text field inputs) as needed.  I am already successfully using jQuery to create these extra fields.  For the sake of this example, let's assume that the following is cloned multiple times:

```
<input name="datain_pline_1" id="datain_pline_1" value="" type="text" class="calc_input" maxlength="4" />
<span id="dataout_currentmult_1"></span>
```

In each new instance of this, the number is being incremented (so datain_pline_1 becomes datain_pline_2, datain_pline_3, etc...and my output span is also incremented accordingly).

I then am running some AJAX on the data that is typed into each field, and returning some output in the relevant span tag.  My code (see below) is working fine for the first field (#1), but i do not know how to edit it to apply the .change function to all my IDs with the similar name...and then how to apply the relevant number also to the span output.  I am relatively new to jQuery but it seems to me from reading about these things that this is not only do-able, but relatively simply...but certainly NOT simple to me!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$("#datain_pline_1").change(function(){

    //Get the data from the field
    var pline = $('input[name=datain_pline_1]');

    //organize the data
    var data = 'pline=' + pline.val() ;

    //start the ajax
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and returns values
        url: "ajax_getPlineData.php",
        //GET method is used
        type: "GET",
        //pass the data
        data: data,
        //Do not cache the page
        cache: false,
        //success
        success: function (outputPlineData) {
            if (outputPlineData!='') {
                //success
                $('#dataout_currentmult_1').html(outputPlineData);
            } else {
                alert('Unexpected Error');
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Where i need help is on the first two lines applying this to all the relevant text input fields (and capturing the value to variable):

```
$("#datain_pline_1").change(function(){
var pline = $('input[name=datain_pline_1]');
```

and the one toward the bottom that outputs the returned data:

```
$('#dataout_currentmult_1').html(outputPlineData);
```

Comment: Thanks to both @swatkins and @scrappedcola!  I am only allowed to chose one "correct" answer, but it was really a combination of the two of you that got me heading in the right direction.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you need to access these more dynamically:

```
// change your spans to have a class
<input name="datain_pline_1" id="datain_pline_1" value="" type="text" class="calc_input" maxlength="4" />
<span id="dataout_currentmult_1" class="calc_output"></span>
```

Then, change those two lines you spoke of to:

```
// target all of the inputs (they all have the class "calc_input")
// updated to "live" per @scrappedcola's comment
$(".calc_input").live('change', function(){

//and
// target the span that is directly after the input that fired the change event
$(this).next('.calc_output').html(outputPlineData);
```

Comment: okay...i am in the process of adding that stuff...but how do i get the value of my text field if i am not determining the current "count"?  I was currently using:  
    var pline = $('input[name=datain_pline_1]');

Comment: but using just the change handler won't get future dynamically added elements unless you reattach the event handler.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that:  You can access the value of the input that initiated the change event with `$(this).val()` -- so change the line `var pline = $('input[name=datain_pline_1]');` to `var pline = $(this);`

Comment: @scrappedcola - that depends on **when** the change handler is attached (before or after the new elements were added to the dom). But I would agree with you to use the `live` or `delegate` methods.

Answer (score 2):

For the `change` handler you if all the inputs have the same class you can use jquery's delegate or live functions which will apply the change event to all current and future elements of that identifier.For the span you could change the span's id to be something similar to `datain_pline_1_SPAN` so that when the change event happens you can get the current id and the span based on that id. For instance:

```
$(".calc_input").live("change", function(){
    var id = this.id;
     var span = $("#" + id + "_SPAN");
    //do rest of stuff here
});
```

or

```
$(document).delegate(".calc_input", "change", function(){
     var id = this.id;
     var span = $("#" + id + "_SPAN");
     //do rest of stuff here
});
```

Comment: I do not understand what this code does.  Is it essentially imbedding the id of the input field within the id of the span?  If so, that does seem like a good way to reference these.  What is the difference between the two options above (delegate and live)?

Comment: yes it is a suggestion to embed the input's id into the span so that when you want to change the values you can directly grab the correct one. A good tutorial on the differences can be found here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/. There are a few differences but the main one is how the event is attached. Delegate attaches to the element where live attaches to the element and bubbles up to the document root. Delegate is a bit more efficient but either will work. Delegate is from jquery 1.4+. Live is included in jquery 1.3+.